# Force break-line to fit text in begin{cases}

Tags: cases

I need to show an equation with begin{cases} however the text is bigger than the column of my article and I couldn't find a way to force it to break the line.

Code:

```
\[
    Match_D = 
\begin{cases}
    1,        & \text{if $D_j$ matches a single detected rectangle,} \\
    0,        & \text{if $D_j$ does not match any detected rectangle,} \\
    f_{sc}(k) & \text{if $D_j$ matches several $(k)$ detected rectangles}
\end{cases}
\]

\[
    Match_G = 
\begin{cases}
    1,        & \text{if $G_i$ matches a single detected rectangle,} \\
    0,        & \text{if $G_i$ does not match any detected rectangle,} \\
    f_{sc}(k) & \text{if $G_i$ matches several $(k)$ detected rectangles}
\end{cases}
\]
```

Regards

Comment: You should input `\mathit{Match}` rather than `Match`: try it and see the difference. Or `\mathrm{Match}`, depending on your preferences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `\parbox` of fixed width:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
  Match_D = 
  \begin{cases}
    1,        & \parbox{.3\linewidth}{if $D_j$ matches a single detected rectangle,} \\[3ex]
    0,        & \parbox{.3\linewidth}{if $D_j$ does not match any detected rectangle,} \\[3ex]
    f_{sc}(k) & \parbox{.3\linewidth}{if $D_j$ matches several $(k)$ detected rectangles}
  \end{cases}
\]

\[
  Match_G = 
  \begin{cases}
    1,        & \parbox[t]{.3\linewidth}{if $G_i$ matches a single detected rectangle,} \\[3ex]
    0,        & \parbox[t]{.3\linewidth}{if $G_i$ does not match any detected rectangle,} \\[3ex]
    f_{sc}(k) & \parbox[t]{.3\linewidth}{if $G_i$ matches several $(k)$ detected rectangles}
  \end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

You can use `[t]`op alignment (see Match_G) or (the default) `[c]`entered alignment (see Match_D).

[image: result]

Answer (score 2):

Two variants without having to measure whatever: one with the `empheq`environment and  `tabular`s, another with the `cases*` environment  from `mathtools`. The first way enables you to easily number or  subnumber each case if you wish. `cases*`is just a `cases` environment in which the 2nd column is automatically in text mode.

It require only loading `empheq`, which loads `mathtools`, which loads `amsmath`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{empheq}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
\begin{empheq}[left={\mathrm{Match}_G=\empheqlbrace}]{alignat=2}
  & 1 & \quad& \begin{tabular}[t]{l}
if $G_i$ matches a single \\ detected rectangle,
\end{tabular} \\
 & 0 & & \begin{tabular}[t]{l}
if $G_i$ does not match \\ any detected rectangle,
\end{tabular} \\
 & f_{sc}(k) & & \begin{tabular}[t]{l}
if $G_i$ matches several \\ $(k)$ detected rectangle,
\end{tabular}
\end{empheq}
\end{subequations}

\[
  \mathrm{Match}_G =
  \begin{cases*}
    1, & if $G_i$ matches a single \\[-0.5ex]
      & detected rectangle, \\%[0.5ex]
    0, & if $G_i$ does not match\\[-0.5ex]
     & any detected rectangle, \\%[0.5ex]
    f_{sc}(k) & if $G_i$ matches several \\[-0.5ex]
     & $(k)$ detected rectangles
  \end{cases*}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I believe this answer is correct too but I just tested the other

Answer (score 0):

I found a more elegant way:

```
\begin{equation}
        Match_D = 
        \begin{cases}
            1,        & \text{if $D_j$ matches a single detected rectangle,} \\
            0,        & \text{if $D_j$ does not match any detected} \\&\text{rectangle}, \\
            f_{sc}(k) & \text{if $D_j$ matches several $(k)$ detected} \\&\text{rectangles}
        \end{cases}
\end{equation}
```

This will ensure your equations in the conditions are rendered correctly, and you can break at any position as you wish.
[image]

Comment: `aligned` doesn't play any role in this result, it's `cases` that does. I just tried removing the `aligned` environment to be sure, the result is identical.

Comment: @Miyase That's right, I just realized that because I always use aligned for line break, not really very versed in its usage.